# How to change particular column value when defined mask is true?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe in which I have these column names

- 'team1',
- 'team2',
- 'city',
- 'date'.

What I want to do is to assign value of 'city' as 'dubai' when certain condition meets(which I am defining using mask).

This is what I am doing exactly:

```
 matches[((matches['team1']=='mi') & (matches['team2']=='rcb') & (matches['date']=='2014-04-19')),'city']='Dubai'
```

When all the above condition meets I want to change value in 'city'(which is null now) to 'Dubai'

The problem which arises:

> 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `.loc` like  `matches.loc[((matches['team1']=='mi') & (matches['team2']=='rcb') & (matches['date']=='2014-04-19')),'city'] = 'Dubai'`

Comment: Thank you sir @JohnGalt Can you explain little bit the difference between the two ? I am getting confused.Thanks anyways

Comment: Read about [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) in pandas. The access methods `pd[ix]` and `pd.col` rely on Numpy indexing and Python attributes, and carry the limitation of those. The pandas-specific access methods such as `.loc[ix, col]` are to be preferred.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bracket (`[]`) notation accesses the `__getitem__` method of a python object (if it has a method defined).  For a `pd.DataFrame` object, you can pass an array like object via the brackets `df[array_like_object]` and it will do one of a few things

***possibility 1***

```
# returns a copy of df with columns ['col1', 'col2']
df[['col1', 'col2']]
```

***possibility 2***

```
# returns a slice of which rows have corresponding trues in the mask
df[boolean_mask]
```

***skipping other possibilities***

---

You've got a `boolean_mask`

```
((matches['team1']=='mi') & 
 (matches['team2']=='rcb') & 
 (matches['date']=='2014-04-19'))
```

And a `column`

```
'city'
```

In this case, it's perfect for `loc` which can process exactly that
Per @JohnGalt

```
matches.loc[
    ((matches['team1']=='mi') &
     (matches['team2']=='rcb') &
     (matches['date']=='2014-04-19')),
    'city'
] = 'Dubai'
```

Comment: Genius! This helped me a ton!